# Is there a way to create a list of values out of existing column value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image: sample_df]

I would like to create a new column with the value of ColB and -1 * ColB. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

[image: resulting_df]

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way:

```
df['ColC'] = df['ColB'].astype(str) + ", " + (df['ColB']*-1).astype(str)
```

Comment: your example output, actualy has lists in the cells, - my solution outputs strings.
be careful

Comment: yes, noticed that and converted it back to float (after exploding)

Comment: if you exploded that column later, most likely, - joining values is an extra step which is not needed at all.

Answer (score 2):

You Can do it like that Direct and clear way

```
def Test(Col1,Col2):
    for i in range(len(Col1)):
        yield [Col1[i],-1*Col2[i]]

z=Test(data["ColB"],data["ColB"])
data["ColC"]=list(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df['ColC'] = df.eval('ColB = -ColB')[['ColA', 'ColB']].values.tolist()
```

```
print(df)

   ColA  ColB     ColC
0     5     1  [5, -1]
1     6     2  [6, -2]
2     7     3  [7, -3]
3     8     4  [8, -4]
4     9     5  [9, -5]
```